# Why is "PDFtk Server" called "PDFtk Server"?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

From looking at the PDFtk Server [product page](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/), [manual](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/), and [example usages](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/), it appears that this is **not actually a server** application - as in runs in the background as a daemon and process requests from clients coming across the network or other processes. Rather it's just a command-line executable run from a shell.

So, why is the word "server" used in the tool's name?

Answer (score 1):

They call it that simply because it doesn't have a GUI -- unlike PDFtk Pro, which does. Assumedly the GUI version is aimed at 'normal' people while PDFtk Server is for sysadmins, devs, etc